# Select data based on another table

Tags: mysql

I have three tables, I'll just list the important columns

**db_players**

id | name

**players**

id | teamid | careerid

**db_teams**

The db_teams id links to the players teamid.

I need to run a query where I select rows from db_players as long as db_teams.id isn't in a row in players as teamid where the careerid = 1.

I've never attempted this type of query with mysql before, I know I could do two queries and involve php but I'm intrigued as to whether it's possible with a pure db query.

Thanks.

EDIT - simpler now.

```
SELECT dp.first_name
FROM tbl_foot_career_db_players dp
INNER JOIN tbl_foot_career_players p
ON p.playerid != dp.id
WHERE p.careerid = 1
```

The idea is that I want to return all rows from tbl_foot_career_db_players WHERE the id from that table isn't present in a row in tbl_foot_career_players in the column playerid. And the tbl_foot_career_players.careerid must also equal 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List all db_players that are not in players with career = 1

```
SELECT d.*
FROM db_players d
LEFT JOIN players p
  ON p.player_id = d.id
  AND p.career = 1
WHERE p.id IS NULL
```

Comment: I'm made a mistake with my original question. The p.teamid needs to equal the id of db_teams. There's a third table in the mix, sorry.

Comment: And how does `db_players` link to `db_teams`?

Comment: It's simpler than I thought. I want to select rows from 'db_players' when db_players.id is not in 'players'.playerid. Simple as that I believe!

Comment: Boom! On the money, cheers bud. Helps me understand left joins, I've always used inner joins where it's all or nothing!

Answer (score 1):

Try to JOIN them with db_players id is not in players teamid.

```
SELECT db_players.* FROM db_players
LEFT JOIN players ON players.id != db_players.id 
LEFT JOIN db_teams ON players.teamid = db_teams.id
WHERE careerid = 1
```

Comment: That ! has made all the difference!

Comment: Sorry, I explained it slightly wrong. There's a third table that needs to come into play. I've revised my question. players.teamid needs to = db_teams.id, not db_players.id.

Comment: It's simpler than I thought. I want to select rows from 'db_players' when db_players.id is not in 'players'.playerid. Simple as that I believe!

Comment: Still doesn't quite work. I'll edit the question with how I've evolved your query to get to what is almost right, it's just still returning all rows rather than excluding them when there is a match.